# How to insert document field value as ISODate with Ruby MongoDB driver?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

It may be really simple, but the obvious is elusive at the moment in Ruby land.

How do I insert document field value as ISODate and NOT a string with Ruby MongoDB driver? When I query a collection inside the MongoDB shell, I want the timestamp to be an ISODate object:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("570348904b3833000addcd67"),
  "timestamp": ISODate("2016-04-04T21:23:52.058Z")
}
```

And **NOT**:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("570348904b3833000addcd67"),
  "timestamp": "2016-04-04T21:23:52.058Z" // or ms since epoch
}
```

Please don't suggest I use ms|s since epoch. It's not a solution here.

I've tried...

```
logs = []
t = Time.at(1448064510963.fdiv(1000))
mongo_hash['timestamp'] = t # --> String
mongo_hash[:timestamp] = t # --> String
mongo_hash['timestamp'] = t.to_datetime # --> Weird Date String
mongo_hash['timestamp'] = t.to_date # --> String without time
logs << mongo_hash
```

I'm pushing `mongo_hash` into an array that's passed into `insert_many`.

```
mongo_client[:logs].insert_many(logs)
```

...and what I get in MongoDB 3.0.x is a string for the timestamp using Ruby Mongo driver v2.2.4...

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("573107ac4f5bd9ac14920bb0"),
  "timestamp": "2015-11-20T11:59:43.127-08:00"
}
```

Piece of cake in JS/Python... why so weird, Ruby? Whyyyy?

Comment: Have you tried to insert a date object?

Comment: @muistooshort - yes, indeed. Tried by first creating `t = Time.at(<ms_since_epoch>.fdiv(1000))` then invoking `t.to_datetime()` within a JSON object pushed into an array that's sent to `mongo_client[:collection].insert_many()`....  still getting either a String value or `TypeError - no implicit conversion of DateTime into String`

Comment: What about `t` itself? Without trying to convert it to a `DateTime` first.

Comment: @muistooshort - I updated the question with all my attempts.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find any documentation on this but if you look at the [official examples](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/master/examples/create.rb), you'll see this:

```
result = client[:restaurants].insert_one({
  #...
  grades: [
    {
      date: DateTime.strptime('2014-10-01', '%Y-%m-%d'),
      grade: 'A',
      score: 11
    },
    #...
  ]
  #...
})
```

That would suggest that you can use simple `DateTime` instances to insert times into MongoDB. So what happens if we try that? Well:

```
irb>  mongo[:pancakes].insert_one(:kind => 'blueberry', :created_at => DateTime.now)
```

and then in MongoDB:

```
> db.pancakes.find()
{ "_id" : ..., "kind" : "blueberry", "created_at" : ISODate("2016-05-15T17:44:12.096Z") }
```

The `ISODate` that we want is there.

Then if we pretend we're in Rails:

```
irb> require 'active_support/all' # To get to_datetime
irb> mongo[:pancakes].insert_one(:kind => 'banana', :created_at => '2016-05-15T06:11:42.235Z'.to_datetime)
```

we get this inside MongoDB:

```
> db.pancakes.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5738b56cf638ccf407c71ef5"), "kind" : "blueberry", "created_at" : ISODate("2016-05-15T17:44:12.096Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5738b74ef638ccf4da4c2675"), "kind" : "banana", "created_at" : ISODate("2016-05-15T06:11:42.235Z") }
```

`ISODate`s again.

I'm using version 2.2.5 of the official Ruby driver here.